# Getting an insufficient memory error in SQL Server Management Studio with no queries open, when trying to open a new, blank query window

Tags: sql-server

Occurred after a reboot on a machine that had been working fine prior.

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

in SQL Server Management Studio (2016, 2017) when attempting to open a new, blank query window.

I've tried restarting the application, repairing the 2017 install and rebooting.

Every mention I find of this error involves people attempting to execute too-large queries or queries with result sets that are too big.

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? Also try setting the memory buffer on the Database Server properties, to 1/2 the current memory pool you have on your machine.

Comment: Is SQL Server running on the same machine? Does it work okay if you shut down SSMS completely and re-open it?

Comment: 16GB - it's got 12GB available - less than 4 in use. The server itself is an AWS RDS sql instance.

Comment: @Aaron - no - server is AWS RDS instance. Same error after restarting app or rebooting computer.

Comment: SSMS is still limited to 2GB. It doesn't matter if you have 16GB or 4TB. I would contact AWS support.

Comment: On a different (client) machine with SSMS installed (same version) I'm able to connect and query the same AWS Instance just fine. I believe this is a client issue entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This is too large for a comment, but I apologise as it's not really an answer as such; more a long comment.

SSMS doesn't  tend to release memory after it's used it, and it's only a 32bit application. Thus, if you run a query that does fill up it's full memory allocation (2GB), and then try to run another query (however simple) then you'll get this error.

The solution is to not run queries that are going to be returning huge results sets in SSMS, it's not designed with that in mind. If the user is planning to export it, use a different tool. `bcp` or `sqlcmd` are 2 perfected suitable tools. If it's a frequent task for a large data export, you might also want to consider using SSIS. There are, of course, plenty of other options out there, I've just listed a few (Microsoft) options, that are also part of the SQL Server product.

Either way, SSMS is not designed for returning massive results sets. It's a development tool first, that allows the user to extract data from the result sets it has returned easily.

Comment: while I agree with you in principal, I'm fairly certain that SSMS hasn't held onto memory through a reboot, and this issue prevents even a blank query window from opening (no other queries open) so I suspect some other issue is to blame.

Comment: @W.L. That wasn't initially implied in your question when I posted this; especially due to your statement: *Every mention I find of this error involves people attempting to execute too-large queries or queries with result sets that are too big.* This really implies that someone is opening the application, running a large resultset query, and then saying they have the error; which i would expect. Are you saying that this happens as soon as a user opens the application, prior to do **anything** else, and it happens on everyone's PC? If so, you might want to have your question reflect this.

Comment: Or, are you you implying that several people are connecting to the same server, all running SSMS, and having the issue? Generally, you shoulnd't be running SSMS on the server, you should be running that locally and connecting to the Server remotely via SSMS. *I will edit these thoughts into the post upon the OP responding, and depending on which is relevant.*

Comment: Larnu - you're right - I thought I had been more specific about the fact that there were no query windows open at all. Problem solved and this error was a red herring, but thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out (in this case) it was a weird share permissions issue. The reboot caused a redirection of the user's HOME folder to remap to a share on the network. Because the machine hadn't been restarted when the policy was put in place, it hadn't taken effect until reboot.

This in itself was harmless, but there was an issue with the permissions on the share that hosted the network home folders, which caused the user to not have write privileges to their own home directories.

This was made apparent later, since the activity of attempting to create a new query window didn't error with a meaningful "can't create file xyz" type error.